# Throttling ,Resource limit exceeded when i try to get credential report in AWS

Tags: amazon-iam

I am trying to generate credential report. I get following error

```
aws iam generate-credential-report

An error occurred (Throttling) when calling the GenerateCredentialReport operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded
```

Also , from boto3 API , I am not getting the report.
Is there any way to set limit?

Comment: i have also tried from UI to generate report , but it says "Your report could not be retrieved. Please try again in a few minutes."

Comment: This error still occurs, what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I opened a support case with AWS about it, here is their response:

> Thank you for contacting AWS about your GetCredentialReport issue. 
>   According to our IAM team, we have observed an increase in the call
>   volume of the IAM GenerateCredentialReport API. In order to avoid any
>   impact that increase in call volume might have on the service and our
>   customers, we blocked that API. Callers will receive LimitExceeded
>   exception. We are actively investigating a solution that will lead to
>   unblocking the API.

Comment: I am very much thankful to you , my sincere gratitude. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll update when they get back to me that it is fixed.  Latest is "The have informed me that they have identified a solution and actively testing it in order to unblock the API."  Feel free to accept this answer.

Comment: I got the same response as Abhishek Upadhyaya.  My jobs that use it are now succeeding too

Comment: I find it astonishing that AWS' response to a capacity problem on their end is to cut off the customers at the knees. Does Azure, Google Cloud and other services have this issue as well?

Answer (score 0):

The API seems to be working now. This is the latest response from AWS Support regarding the issue:

> "We have deployed a fix to the GenerareCredentialReport API issue
>   which will protect the IAM service from elevated latencies and error
>   rates. We are going to ramp up the traffic to the API over the next
>   few days. In the meanwhile, clients calling the API might receive
>   “LimitExceed Exception”. In this case, we recommend that the clients
>   retry with exponential back off."